# Is Anular's emulated shadow DOM html standard conform and why does nobody care?

Tags: html, angular, w3c, w3c-validation

Angular uses shadow DOM to encapsule styles for it's components:

> In Angular, a component's styles can be encapsulated within the component's host element so that they don't affect the rest of the application.

https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

There is different ways of encapsulation `ShadowDom`and `emulated`. While the first one produces html standard conform code, the later does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  <app-root _nghost-ng-c2283532919="" ng-version="17.1.3">
    <h1 _ngcontent-ng-c2283532919="">Headline</h1>
  </app-root>
  <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Angular uses the `_ngcontent-ng-c2283532919` attribute to identify the emulated shadow DOM, but the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) fails on this.

The HTML standard described by [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/) says:

> 3.2.6 Global attributes
>
> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification):
>
> ...

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes

and

> Custom data attributes (e.g. data-foldername or data-msgid) can be specified on any HTML element, to store custom data, state, annotations, and similar, specific to the page.
>
> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no ASCII upper alphas.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html

Angular uses the additional attributes without the `data-` prefix:

```
<h1 _ngcontent-ng-c2283532919="">
```

Even though the reason for this kind of solution seems convincing:

> The main reason for that is that back in the day when Angular was created; most browsers were not supporting Shadow Dom.

https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/the-difference-between-angulars-emulated-shadow-dom-and-native-shadow-dom-9b2c81546b85

Why does Angular use non standard HTML markup?

or

Why would this markup still be valid and are there any references why it would be?

Comment: Browsers are made in a forward-compatible way: Everything they do not understand, they should ignore. This made it possible to introduce the `noscript` tag, which newer browsers understood to not render if you have scripting enabled, but older browsers would just render as normal text as if the new tag was just a div. IIRC this was not explicitly so for HTML attributes but just worked out that way. Using `data-` prefix is just the official way for user-defined attributes. But if you try something non-confirming and it works in all browsers... I guess it's conforming then. Just not formally.